# How to skip the need to confirm an email address update with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using `rails` with `devise` `confirmable`.

Generally I want to have users confirm their email address, however sometimes I need to manually change an email on behalf of an existing user and I want to skip sending the confirmation email.

When *creating* a new user I can skip the confirmation email with:

```
user.skip_confirmation!
```

...but this does not appear to work for existing, already confirmed users - insofar as the email attribute is not updated, and `devise` still requires the user to confirm the new email and sends out a confirmation email:

```
@user = User.find_by_email('bob@site.example')
@user.email = 'dead@site.example'
@user.skip_confirmation!
@user.save!
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The method you want to use is `skip_reconfirmation!` (note the '**re'** in reconfirmation).

```
@user = User.find_by_email('bob@site.example')
@user.email = 'dead@site.example'
@user.skip_email_changed_notification!
@user.save!
```

Comment: Awesome! this is insane... `skip_confirmation!`should also include this case! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Beware: the code example was erroneously edited to include skip_email_changed_notification! instead of correct skip_reconfirmation!.

Appears to be based on a misunderstanding. There are two places in Devise code that send emails on email change and the original question is about one in ::Confirmable, which is skipped by using skip_reconfirmation!; it wasn't changed to skip_email_changed_notification! in Devise

Answer (score 16):

Try setting `Devise.reconfirmable` or `User.reconfirmable` (or whatever your model is) to false. You can set it on `config/initializers/devise.rb` on this line:

```
# If true, requires any email changes to be confirmed (exctly the same way as
# initial account confirmation) to be applied. Requires additional unconfirmed_email
# db field (see migrations). Until confirmed new email is stored in
# unconfirmed email column, and copied to email column on successful confirmation.
config.reconfirmable = true
```

You can also use Active Record's `update_column` method, which saves a field without running callbacks or validations.

Comment: I want reconfirmable, what I want to do is have the ability to skip reconfirmable when updating an email for an existing user record

Answer (score 7):

You can use this kind of code in your model `# models/users.rb`. This will disable email reconfirmation on update:

```
def postpone_email_change?
  false 
end
```

or in your controller

```
def update
  user.email = params[:user][:email]
  user.skip_confirmation_notification!

  if user.save
    user.confirm
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to skip reconfirmation for a specific user, you may go for following:

```
user = User.find_by(email: 'some.email@example.com')
user.email = 'new.email@example.com'
user.skip_reconfirmation!
user.save!
```

If you want to remove reconfirmation functionality from your application and update email as soon as you update it and not send a notification, go to `config/devise.rb` and change the value of

```
config.reconfirmable = true
```

to

```
config.reconfirmable = false
```

Note that, if you have reconfirmable option true in devise.rb, any email update will be saved in unconfirmed_email column in database until you comfirm it from the email.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip just the email notification, do this:

```
@user.skip_confirmation_notification!
@user.save
```

Answer (score 0):

When updating the email use skip_**re**confirmation!

> skip_reconfirmation!

```
@user = User.find_by_email('bob@site.example')
@user.email = 'dead@site.example'
@user.skip_reconfirmation!
@user.save!
```